# TEST-INJECTION and TEST-SEAM in ABAP code

Tags: unit-testing, testing, abap

I’m trying to use `TEST-INJECTION` and `TEST-SEAM` in my code. I have following code:

```
CLASS lcl_undertest DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS mymethod RETURNING VALUE(r) TYPE string.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_undertest IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD mymethod.
    TEST-SEAM vypis.
      r = 'abc'.
    END-TEST-SEAM.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS ltc_testclass DEFINITION FOR TESTING RISK LEVEL HARMLESS DURATION SHORT FINAL.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
    METHODS test_method1 FOR TESTING.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS ltc_testclass IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD test_method1.

    TEST-INJECTION vypis.
      r = 'xyz'.
    END-TEST-INJECTION.

    DATA(res) = lcl_undertest=>mymethod( ).
    cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_equals(
      act   = res
      exp   = 'xyz'
      msg   = 'nespravny text'
    ).

  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
WRITE / lcl_undertest=>mymethod( ) .
```

For these lines

```
    TEST-INJECTION vypis.
      r = 'xyz'.
    END-TEST-INJECTION.
```

these three following errors are indicated:

> 1. No injection is expected here.
> 2. Field "R" is unknown.
> 3. Incorrect nesting: For the statement "END-TEST-INJECTION", there is no open structure introduced by "TEST-INJECTION".

I’ve also tried to copy some example codes from documentation and blogs, but there were same errors returned.

What is the reason of problems?

Comment: Is all your code in an executable program? I.e. the 'main' class and the testclass as well? (Menu: Goto => Attributes / Popup => Field "Type")

Comment: See docu: "Injections can only be created in test classes that are defined in a test include of the current program. Test includes are currently only possible in class pools and function groups. This means that test seams are only feasible in class pools and function groups."

Comment: @petul please convert your comment into an answer, this is probably the good answer (PS: it can be interesting to say that test seams exist since abap 7.50, too)

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai: Yes, it is executable. I’ve omitted first line of code (REPORT).

Comment: @jcjr it looks like that is the issue, as pointed out by petul as well. I think it only works this way: class created in SE24 and test class also there (Pushbutton Local test classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the documentation regarding test-seams [here](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abaptest-seam.htm).

> Note
>
> Injections can only be created in test classes that are defined in a
>   test include of the current program. Test includes are currently only
>   possible in class pools and function groups. This means that test
>   seams are only feasible in class pools and function groups.

Also be aware that they only exist since ABAP release 7.50 (thanks to [Sandra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9150270/sandra-rossi))

To make it clear: the documentation speaks of class pools, meaning that it won't work in e.g. reports. You'll have to declare a global class with the local test class defined in its test include.

Comment: My SAP version is 7.50 (if lower, error message would be different). It is executable program with this code. According to the error messages, there is no problem with SEAMs. How should I change the code or the ‘architecture’ to make it work?

Comment: @jcjr You need a "real" class. Then navigate to the test include (SE80: Ctrl+Shift+F11, eclipse: Test Classes tab at the bottom)

Comment: It works now! I would rather say "it has to be in a global class, not local". Both of them seem 'real' to me. Can you add it to your post to make it 100% clear? Anyway, your hint got me there. Thanks!

Comment: @jcjr class pools in ABAP actually means global class. But I can add it for clarification